# Trying to find depth of binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I'm trying to write something to determine the largest depth of a binary tree but far have only ended up with one thing that keep giving back the number of nodes in the tree, and another, below, that is always one more or less off. After hours of trying to adjust this I could really use some advice..

```
void findthedepth(nodeoftree<node>* root, int* depthtotal, int* depthcurrent){

    int left = 0, right = 0;

    if( root == nullptr ){
        *depthtotal = 0;
        *depthcurrent = 0;
        return;
    }

    findthedepth(root->rightp(), depthtotal, depthcurrent);
    right = *depthcurrent;

    *depthcurrent = 0;

    findthedepth(root->leftp(), depthtotal, depthcurrent);
    left = *depthcurrent;


    if (left > right){ 
        *depthtotal += left + 1;
    }
    else { 
        *depthtotal += right + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend removing those pointers, and simply returning the value. It makes the code much easier to read, and probably easier to find the issue.

Comment: You never seem to actually write to `depthcurrent` in the non-empty case, so get rid of it. You can then fix up your recursive call by doing `findthedepth(root->rightp(), &right)` (and similarly for left). Your final write to `depthtotal` is correct. Definitely switch to either return a value outright or taking a *reference* to `depthcurrent`.

Answer (score 5):

There are two cases to consider:

- An empty tree has depth zero;
- A non-empty tree has one level more than the depth of its two subtrees, so it has depth `1 + max(depth_left, depth_right)`.

If we write this out in C++:

```
int depth(nodeoftree<node>* root) {
    if (root == nullptr)
        return 0;

    int depth_left = depth(node->leftp());
    int depth_right = depth(node->rightp());
    return 1 + max(depth_left, depth_right);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close, you don't need the `depthCurrent` pointer

```
   findthedepth(root->rightp(), depthtotal /*, depthcurrent*/);
   right = *depthtotal; // update the total depth captured in right

   // *depthcurrent = 0; (no use)

   findthedepth(root->leftp(), depthtotal /*, depthcurrent*/);
   left = *depthtotal; // update the total depth captured in left
```